# Qt C++ cannot call member function '~~ const' without object

Tags: c++, qt

I keep getting this error:

```
   cannot call member function 'bool QDir::mkpath(const QString&) const' without object
```

My code:

```
  QStringList lists;
  lists << "ABC/DEF" << "GHI/JKL" << "MLO/PQR";
  foreach (QString cdir, lists)
     if (!QDir(cdir).exists()) QDir::mkpath(cdir);
```

I really don't know how to modify this code.
Please Help me how to use QDir::mkpath with QStringList. Thanks.

Comment: `QDir::mkpath()` is not a static function. You cannot call it in that way. You have to create a `QDir` object and call `mkpath()` function on it.

Comment: Above comment is correct. You need to make a temp instance to perform that function. It would be nice if it was static though.

Comment: Thank you so much, vahancho and Mike~~~ ^^. It's solved.